# Post service ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cordova, post

I have a webservice to authentificate my user (from an app made with cordova) :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/RegisterUser")]
    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Authenticate")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetUserAuthenticated(string userName, string pwd)
        {
             //Code here
        }
    }
```

with cordova I use this :

```
let data = {
    FK_BaseID:2,
    FK_UserTypeID: this.IDs.userType,
    Username: regData.email.toLowerCase(),
    Password: regData.password,
}
this._http.post('RegisterUser', data);
```

But I get this error :

```
"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '..../RegisterUser/Authentificate'.",
"MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'RegisterUser'."
```

My service was working fine with HttpGet but I can't manage to make it work with post.

I've tried something like this :

```
public IHttpActionResult GetUserAuthenticated(string body)
{
    return Ok(body);
}
```

using [FromBody] also, but I'm unable to make it work. I've seen a few examples using Request.Form to navigate through the body of the request and thus the parameters. But my Request hasn't any Form property.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You are posting to this url: ..../RegisterUser/Authentificate. But your method is called GetUserAuthenticated. So either match the name or write a custom route for that

Comment: He defined the route with [Route("Authenticate")], so he already defined his custom route.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the "body" param with a class or struct typedef
the way that the routing mechanism works is by matching methods and parameters received to those one who already been registered (see ApiExplorer class for instance in WebApi; this is how the asp App is actually booting itself into a full state web "actions receiver and invoker")

What happens with your code is, in my humble understanding, is that the app is searching for a complex parameter to build the "body" parameter since it is a POST message (hence the attribute name "FromBody") and thus fails to find an entry in the BODY sector of the http message for a complex "body" segment

just wrap the parameter with a class, i.e 
public class MyMessage { public string Body {get;set;} }

- notice here that this is actually the same as your code since the "MyMessage" identifier is actually not anywhere to be seen in the body of the message, and is a good example to understand since the web app mechanism actually does this kind of "pairing" on its own based on the url you have provided and the compile time signatures you have imposed on the action implementation

Answer (score 0):

I'll do it like this :

```
public class AuthenticateViewModel {
      public string Username {get; set;}
      public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

And in your controller :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/RegisterUser")]
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Authenticate")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetUserAuthenticated([FromBody]AuthenticateViewModel model){
         var userName = model.Username;
         var pwd = model.Password;
         // Code logic here.
         return Ok(model);
    }
}
```

The names of your parameters have to match for the binding to execute.

You may want to check your client code also, seems like you're not posting on the right url :

```
let data = {
    FK_BaseID:2,
    FK_UserTypeID: this.IDs.userType,
    Username: regData.email.toLowerCase(),
    Password: regData.password,
}
this._http.post('api/RegisterUser/Authenticate', data);
```